# Треугольник паскаля без массивов

Tags: java, алгоритм

Как написать алгоритм, который выводит в консоль треугольник паскаля, не используя при этом массивы?

```
p.s. 
1
1 1
1 2 1
1 3 3 1
1 4 6 4 1
и т.д.

p.p.s мне никаких идей не приходит :(
```

Comment: Если сделайте еще и подсветку четных чисел в этом треугольнике увидите треугольник Серпинского внутри.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Давайте немного проанализируем.

Если верить википедии (или школьному маткружку), элементы треугольника паскаля обозначаются C(n, k) и называются биномиальными коэффициентами. Они вычисляются по формуле

```
C(n, k) = n! / (k! (n-k)!)
```

Но считать факториалы на каждом шаге не очень эффективно, поэтому давайте найдём рекуррентные соотношения.

1.

```
C(n, 0) = n! / (0! n!) = 1.
```

2.

```
C(n, k) / C(n, k-1) = (n! / (k! (n-k)!)) * (n! / ((k-1)! (n-k+1)!) =
                    = ((k-1)! (n-k+1)!) / (k! (n-k)!) =
                    = ((k-1)! / k!) * ((n-k+1)! / (n-k)!) =
                    = (1/k) * (n-k+1) =
                    = (n-k+1)/k.
```

Отлично, у нас есть всё, что нужно.

Код:

```
import static java.lang.System.out;
//...
for (int n = 0; ?; n++)
{
    int Cnk = 1; // согласно (1)
    out.print(Cnk);
    for (int k = 1; k <= n; k++)
    {
        Cnk *= (n - k + 1); // согласно (2)
        Cnk /= k;           // тут обязано делиться нацело
        out.print(" "); out.print(Cnk);
    }
    out.println();
}
```

Проверка: http://ideone.com/BTObLZ

Comment: @VladD, а что означает  

    for (int n = 0; ?; n++)
?

Comment: @ReinRaus: ну, туда надо что-нибудь вписать, но у меня не хватило фантазии :-) например, `n < N`.

Comment: @VladD, ну вот, а я минут пять убил гугля что значит вопрос в цикле :)

Comment: @ReinRaus: сорри :)

Answer (score 6):

Каждое значение ячейки вычисляется следующим образом

```
X(i, j) = X(i - 1, j) + X(i - 1, j - 1)
```

где i - строка, j - колонка. Причем если j = 0 или i = j, то значение равно 1.

Получаем рекуррентное отношение и решаемую рекурсивно задачу без использования массивов.

```
public class Pascal {

public static int pascal(int i, int j) {
    return (j == 0 || j == i) ? 1 : pascal(i - 1, j - 1) + pascal(i - 1, j);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    for (int i = 0; i <= 10; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j <= i; j++) {
            System.out.print(pascal(i, j) + " ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Вам придётся запоминать предыдущую строку, так что без массивов не обойтись.

Comment: Вернее если j==0 или i==j

Comment: @VladD дополнил ответ примером кода. Никаких массивов.

Comment: @a_gura: а, понял, рекурсия. Согласен, не сообразил сразу.

ЗЫ: но ваше решение всё же `О(2^n)`.

Comment: @VladD Вычислительная сложность вашего решения без сомнения меньше.

Comment: @a_gura: не сочтите за критику, ТС не выдвигал никаких требований по производительности.

Comment: @VladD какая уж тут критика. Важное и полезное замечание.

Answer (score 5):

А в чем проблема просто написать метод, который высчитывает (С из n по k) и прогнать по нужным значениям?
Как раз никакого массива использоваться и не будет.

Comment: кароче, проблема сводится лишь к реализации факториала..)
Думаю, это не самая большая проблема

Comment: @Stas0n: быстрая реализация факториала не так уж проста. Во-первых,  `20!` не влезет в long, придётся использовать BigInteger. Во-вторых, придётся сосчитать заранее и закешировать таблицу факториалов.

Comment: @VladD Закешировать и "без массивов" -- противоречие.

Comment: @alexlz: ваша правда.

Comment: @alexlz: а BigInteger наверняка внутри тоже массивы использует...

Comment: @VladD " а BigInteger наверняка внутри тоже массивы использует...". Так ведь и integer внутри -- тоже массив бит. Это уже буквоедство. А вот самопальный кэш или ещё какое динамическое программирование -- уже прямое нарушение правил задачи.

Comment: @alexlz: не совсем буквоедство. Под требованием "не использовать массивы" я понимаю "О(1) по расходу памяти" (иначе массив можно рассовать по переменным). Integer удовлетворяет этому условию, BigInteger -- нет, так как факториал по размеру где-то `n^n`, а значит, требует O(n log n) разрядов. Убедил?

Comment: @VladD слишком умно. Не представляю, чтобы студентам младших курсов давали такие хитрые задания. По-моему массивы просто должны отсутствовать в тексте программы

Comment: @alexlz: ну смотрите: если я использую массивы, но мой расход памяти O(1), то в массиве заранее ограниченное к-во элементов, и я смогу тупо переписать код, заменив массив `a` на переменные `a0`, `a1`, ..., `a100` (или сколько их там). То есть если я по памяти О(1), массивы фактически не обязательны. Если же я по памяти не ограничен, без массивов никак не закодируешь. А требование просто не использовать тип данных "массив" в программе легко обходится, будем писать в `HashMap<int, Object>`. Или в файл! :-D

Comment: @VladD дискуссия без малейшего смысла. Если задача не чисто учебная, то массивы предполагаются (варианты жёстких ограничений по памяти не шибко реальны. А так получается как в одном старом советском анекдоте, где учащийся Школы Рабочей Молодёжи с бодуна у доски выводит формулу объёма шара, но путает знак интеграла.

Comment: @alexlz: поделитесь анекдотом? (да, оффтопик)

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void tr(int n){

        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            int number  = 1;
            System.out.format("%"+(n - i)*2+"s","");
            for (int j = 0; j <= i; j++) {
                System.out.printf("%4d", number);
                number=number * (i - j) / (j + 1); 
            }
            System.out.println("");
        }

    }
```