# Кривая Безье произвольного порядка.

Tags: математика, алгоритм, php

Товарищи программисты-математики, отдаю на ваш справедливый суд данный класс.
Некоторые очевидные методы, вроде lineTo я убрал, чтобы не было tl;dr, то есть, это выжимка интересующих меня моментов.

```
<?php
/**
 * Class point
 */
class point{
    public $x;
    public $y;

    /**
     * @param $x
     * @param $y
     */
    function __construct($x=false,$y=false){
        $this->x = $x?$x:rand(1,IMG_SIZE_X);
        $this->y = $y?$y:rand(1,IMG_SIZE_Y);
    }

    /**
     * @param point $p
     * @param float $dist
     *
     * @return point
     */
    function midPoint(point $p,$dist=0.5){
        $new_x = $this->x+($p->x-$this->x)*$dist;
        $new_y = $this->y+($p->y-$this->y)*$dist;
        $new_point = new point($new_x,$new_y);
        return $new_point;
    }
}

/**
 * Class bezierimage
 */
class bezierimage{
    private $img;
    public $color;
    public $bgcolor;
    public $brush_position;
    function __construct(){
        $this->img = imagecreatetruecolor(IMG_SIZE_X,IMG_SIZE_Y);
        $this->color = imagecolorallocate($this->img,255,255,255);
    }

    /**
     * @param point[]   $points
     * @param float     $dist
     *
     * @return point[]
     */
    function getBezierPoints($points,$dist=0.5){
        if(count($points)==1){
            return $points[0];
        }
        $new_points = array();
        for($i=1;$i<count($points);$i++){
            $new_points[] = $points[$i-1]->midPoint($points[$i],$dist);
        }
        return $this->getBezierPoints($new_points,$dist);
    }
    /**
     * @param point[]   $points
     * @param int       $precision
     */
    function bezierCurve($points,$precision=700){
        foreach($points as $point){
            $this->putPixel($point);
        }
        for($i=0;$i<$precision;$i++){
            $dist = $i/$precision;
            $this->lineTo($this->getBezierPoints($points,$dist),2);
        }
    }
}
```

Можно ли, не прибегая к другим языкам, оптимизировать данный код? Он заметно начинает тормозить уже на порядке 70, а на 100 просто утыкается в ограничение по вложенности рекурсии. Особенно интересуют два момента:
метод getBezierPoints - оптимизация
метод bezierCurve - динамический подбор количества полигонов, в зависимости от кривизны линии на данном отрезке.

По поводу сторонних библиотек: к сожалению, чаще всего находятся максимум 3-4 порядка, так что не вариант, разве что собрать свою.

P.S. таки да, я опять пытаюсь использовать PHP в целях, для которых он не предназначен. Но интерес больше академический, для практики и правда более 6-10 точек не надо.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

По поводу `getBezierPoints` — можно сделать в один проход без рекурсии.

Смотрите. Пусть в начале у нас есть точки `p[0]`, ..., `p[n-1]`. После первого шага у нас получается `q[0] = (p[0] + p[1]) / 2`, `q[1] = (p[1] + p[2]) / 2`, ..., `q[n-2] = (p[n-2] + p[n-1]) / 2`, то есть

```
q[i] = (p[i] + p[i+1]) / 2.
```

На следующем шаге

```
r[i] = (q[i] + q[i+1]) / 2 = (p[i] + 2p[i+1] + p[i+2]) / 4.
```

Видно, что возникают биномиальные коэффициенты:

```
r[i] = (C_2^0 p[i + 0] + C_2^1 p[i + 1] + C_2^2 p[i + 2]) / 2^2.
```

(Немного математики: По индукции легко доказать, что биномиальные коэффициенты будут и дальше: если на `j`-м уровне

```
s[i] = (\sum_k=0^{j-1} C_j^k p[i + k]) / 2^j,
```

то на `(j+1)`-м

```
t[i] = (s[i] + s[i+1]) / 2 =
     = (\sum_k=0^j (C_j^k + C_j^{k + 1}) p[i + k]) / 2^{j + 1}
     = (\sum_k=0^j C_{j + 1}^k p[i + k]) / 2^{j + 1}.
```

База индукции очевидна.)

Итак, нам нужны биномиальные коэффициенты. Их можно тоже [легко вычислить на лету](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/182043). Конечный алгоритм должен быть таким:

```
int l = count($points);
int coeff = 1;
point result = $points[0];
for (int idx = 1; idx < l; idx++)
{
    coeff *= (l - idx);
    coeff /= idx;
    result += $points[idx] * coeff;
}
result /= (1 << (l - 1)); // степень двойки
```

---

Если делить надо не обязательно на 2, аналогично получается вот что:

```
int l = count($points);
double alpha = 0.333333; // или любое другое значение между 0 и 1
double beta = 1 - alpha;
double beta2alpha = beta / alpha;
int coeff = alpha ** (l - 1); // степень
point result = $points[0] * coeff;
for (int idx = 1; idx < l; idx++)
{
    coeff *= (l - idx);
    coeff /= idx;
    coeff *= beta2alpha;
    result += $points[idx] * coeff;
}
```

Comment: q[i] = (p[i] + p[i+1]) / 2

Если нужно делить не на 2, а на произвольное(хоть и одинаковое для всех точек) число, нас коэффициенты спасут? Я, признаться, всегда в цэ-ка-по-цэ-эн был слаб.

Comment: @knes: Насколько я понимаю, да. Там на самом деле нужно `p[i] * q + p[i+1] * (1 - q)`. Сейчас продумаю, что нужно поменять.

Comment: В википедии формула, кажется что надо. И если B(t) - это как раз point::, то все как вы написали. Меня только смущает сотая степень.

Comment: @knes: добавил. А где сотая степень?

Comment: >int coeff = alpha ** (l - 1);

Если точек 101, то тут сотая степень. Или я опять ничего не понял?

Comment: @knes: всё правильно, сотая степень. Для стартового коэфициента у нас `alpha^100`, для следующего `alpha^99 * beta`, затем `alpha^98 * beta^2` и т. д. Это замена для `(0.5)^100`.

Comment: Вообще шик. 5000 точек с точностью 2000 считается всего 5 секунд.

Comment: @knes: отлично!