# Gd сглаживание линии

Tags: php

В общем, это в тему к [предыдущему вопросу](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/215069/php-%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D0%B1%D0%B5%D0%B7%D1%8C%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8F%D0%B4%D0%BA%D0%B0), но речь совсем о другом.

GD умеет рисовать линию, толщиной один пиксель, без сглаживания.
В комментариях к [функции line](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.imageline.php) есть пример как нарисовать толстую линию. Казалось бы, вот оно решение: рисуем толстую линию и втрое большее разрешение рисунка, потом ужимаем до нужного размера при помощи imagecopyresampled, но это большие затраты, вообще-то, особенно, если требуется нарисовать что-то с большим разрешением.

Когда-то я читал про алгоритм рисования сразу сглаженной линии в какой-то книжке по паскалю. Но тогда это мне было не нужно, а сейчас не могу найти.
Ткните носом, плиз.

P.S. обязательное условие, которое нарушается при уменьшении изображения: цепочка ярких пикселей должна быть непрерывна, даже если прямая проходит "посередине" между двумя пикселями.

B - черный
G - серый
g - светло-серый
W - белый

```
WWWWWWWW
WBBBBggW
WggGGBBW
WWWWWWWW
```

Comment: Вообще возможно не про то думаю но сглаженые лини рисутся через GD просто надо установить imageantialias в true для картиник.

Comment: >Использование сглаженных примитивов совместно с прозрачным фоном может дать неожидаемый результат. Метод смешивания использует цвет фона на равне с любым другим цветом. Отсутствие поддержки альфа компонента не позволяет применять основанный на нем метод сглаживания.

А так - да, почти то чно надо. Но оно не работает с альфой и оно плохо работает с тонкими линиями

Comment: http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D0%BB%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BC_%D0%92%D1%83

Comment: Непрерывных тут не достигается. 
А представляю я это так же как это выглядит в досовских играх периода 1992-1995 годов. Четкие контуры, слегка сглаженные в изгибах. Другое дело, там это было нарисовано вручную.

Предложенный вами алгоритм с большой степенью соответствует тому, что прислал binliz. Настолько, что я уже подумываю просто нарисовать подряд две линии: сглаженную, а сверху - без сглаживания.

Comment: ну вы просто ставьте точки и по Брезерхейму и по Ву, в одном проходе, ну или градаций по Ву возьмите 3-4 всего. А в досовских играх сглаживание было в основном за счет мониторов. Вы бы еще спектрум вспомнили :)

Comment: Вот про мониторы не надо. Я на современном мониторе запускал игры в досбоксе без фильтров, то же самое. 
Titus the fox, Simon the sorcerer, kyrandia и подобные. Надо признать, там очень неплохая графа для тех технических средств, которые были.

Увы, спектрума не вспомню. У меня был БК 1001, а потом сразу 286

Comment: выше перечисленные игры - спрайтовые, там художники специально пиксели подбирали, без всяких алгоритмов. а вот вы вспомните Elite и прочие векторные игрушки.